# Proper FBX import/PY script

Tags: rigging, armature, import

I have a question about proper import character game models into blender. Below you can see how blender handle importing the model:[image: Blender Armature]

Where other software import it properly - like this:
[image: Other 3D software]

Is there any way to properly import model into blender to maintain IK chains - once I cleaned whole armature manually but that created another problem - I couldn't use game ready animations.

Or is there a possibility to use .py script to make whole editing and connecting bones automatic - because its almost impossible to work even with 1 model because there is hundreds of game ready animations that would need to be changed in the same way as rigged character.